# SSIS Job Change Schedule

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to change a job start time in SQL Server by **Removing** the existing schedule and creating a new one.

[image]

Unfortunately, Microsoft doesn't want to let me delete the existing schedule from the job. I get the error

> Only owner...can delete the job schedule.

[image]

**I am the owner**. I created the job using the same login that I am using to change it. **My username** is in the properties **as the Owner** (FU MS).

I am only trying to remove the schedule from the Job but the error seems to indicate that I am trying to delete the schedule. I think my original mistake was to use an existing schedule rather than create a new duplicate one.

How do I work-around (yet another stupid) permission problem? Or am I doing this wrong?

If it didn't have so many steps, I would just (try to) delete it.

Comment: Hm, Just other bypass can be - You push with the mouse right key on tje job and choose Script job as ... Create... then for you will be generated script with all the steps, you just remove that line or lines where schedule set is.... change the name of job and can execute script. Will be created new job.

Comment: Thanks, Justin. Evidently, there is no way to change the schedule if you choose one instead of creating a new one. No wonder there are so many. I will **NEVER use an existing schedule** again.